# Return pointer value changes after passing out from a method

Tags: c++, pointers, eigen

I have a strange behavior with the following code using `Eigen` library.

If I assign the pointer to `DoubleListCg->doubles`, then the value I get for the `DoubleListCg->doubles[i]` is wrong. But if I assign the element one by one, then the value I get for the pointer array above is correct. Why?

This is my code below:

```
#define DllExport   __declspec( dllexport ) 

#include "stdafx.h"
#define EIGEN_USE_MKL_ALL
#include <iostream>
#include "Eigen/Dense"
#include "Eigen/src/Core/util/MKL_support.h"
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
#include <Eigen/Eigenvalues>
#include <vector>
#include <Eigen/PardisoSupport>
using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

extern "C" struct DllExport DoubleListCg
{
    int num_points;
    double* doubles;
};

// working
void DoubleList(VectorXd vector, DoubleListCg *dListPtr)
{
    dListPtr->num_points = vector.size();
   dListPtr->doubles= (double*) malloc ( dListPtr->num_points*sizeof(double));
   for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++)
   {
       dListPtr->doubles[i]=vector[i];
   }     

}

//not working
void DoubleList2(VectorXd vector, DoubleListCg *dList)
{
    dList->num_points = vector.size();
    dList->doubles =vector.data();

}

void VectorConvert()
{
    VectorXd vector(3);
    vector<<1,2,3;

    DoubleListCg dList;
    DoubleList(vector, &dList);  //this works; the dList gets the right values at first element

    DoubleListCg dList2;
    DoubleList2(vector, &dList2)  //this doesn't work; the dList2 gets the wrong values at first element


}
```

It must be something really elementary that I hang up.

**Related question:** Is there anyway that I can point `dList->doubles` at the `vector.data()`? I don't want to copy everything over and over again

Comment: Why this question was downvoted and voted for closure ( for the reason of not-reproducible)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//not working
void DoubleList2(VectorXd vector, DoubleListCg *dList)
{
    dList->num_points = vector.size();
    dList->doubles =vector.data();
}
```

In above function `vector` is local variable to function `DoubleList2`. When the function returns or gets completed then this local variable gets destroyed and `dList->doubles` becomes a dangling pointer and it leads to Undefined Behavior if such dangling pointer is accessed.

Correct implementation would be:

```
void DoubleList2(VectorXd vector, DoubleListCg *dList)
{
    dList->num_points = vector.size();
    dList->doubles = (double*) malloc ( dList->num_points*sizeof(double));
    memcpy(dList->doubles, vector.data(), dList->num_points*sizeof(double));
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway that I can point `dList->doubles` at the `vector.data()`? I don't want to copy everything over and over again

Comment: Use vector by reference as suggested by @Avi Ginsburg.  Also make sure the lifetime of vector is valid at the place of accessing `dList->doubles`.

Comment: Isn't your correct implementation a copy of all of data from `vector.data()` to `dList->doubles`?

Comment: Yes, its a copy of data from vector. But this approach will keep things independent. That is, `dList` will not depend upon some external data source.

Answer (score 3):

In `void DoubleList(VectorXd vector, DoubleListCg *dListPtr)` `vector` is a (temporary) copy of the argument. When you allocate memory and then copy the values into it, they are retained in `dListPtr`. In the not working case, the `.data()` pointer points to a temporarily allocated array. When it goes out of scope, the memory is not guaranteed to remain allocated. If you pass `vector` by reference, then the memory will remain allocated until the original is out of scope.

Comment: I see. Is there anyway that I can directly pointing the `dList->doubles` at the `vector.data()`? I don't want to copy everything over and over again

Comment: You can pass it by reference (`DoubleList(VectorXd &vector...`). Just note that this won't work if you pass an expression to `DoubleList`, i.e. `DoubleList(3.0 * vec...)`.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by pass an expression to `DoubleList`?

Comment: If you call `DobleList` with an expression (e.g. `DoubleList(matrix * vec, dListPtr123);` the expression `matrix * vec` will be evaluated to a temporary object. This temporary object will go out of scope when the function finishes and the pointer in `dListPtr123` will remain pointing at the temporary data array (a dangling pointer).